# What's going on with this =+ assignment?

Tags: php, operators, assignment-operator

I accidentially stumbled over the following code snippet that had me scratch my head for quite a while:

```php
$sum = 0; $realSum = 0;

foreach (range(0,5) as $number) {
    $sum =+ $number;
    $realSum += $number
}

echo "Sum: $sum, RealSum: $realSum"; 
// prints 'Sum: 5, RealSum: 15'
?>
```

What I wanted was obviously the `+=` statement, but somehow PHP wouldn't raise any errors or warnings about the `+=` at all. My IDE also didn't complain about it.

What's this `=+` thing in `$sum =+ $number`? I couldn't find anything on this in the [official documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php).

Comment: @Sean `=+` is not a typo, I didn't confuse it with `+=`. Thanks for the pointer though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sign is the sign of the number. So if `$number` equals 3, if you put `-$number`, the value will be -3.

Comment: That makes sense. I was somehow confused about why PHP would accept this (superfluous) `+` after the assignment. Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 1):

```
$sum =+$number;
```

This one is like $sum = 0 + $number, it gets last value of the array which is `5`

```
$realSum += $number;
```

But this one is like $realSum = $realSum + $number

Comment: It is not `0 + $number` it is just the sign of the number.

Comment: In Math it's like that, we assume that zero is there, the assignment is right I didn't mentioned because I thought its just usual thing and basic math info

Comment: Joyas answer makes more sense, as the PHP 'interpreter' only accepts `=+` and `=-`. I just tried `=* $number` as a shorthand for `= 0 * $number`, which yields a syntax error. Thanks for the hint though.

Comment: This is depends on PHP, *number is true, php should assume 1*number instead